# Control foreign objects created by other canvas libraries

Tags: canvas, 3d, 2d, three.js, paperjs

I am wondering if it is possible to create 2D elements using paper.js and have them live on a shared canvas with and being moved in 3D space by three.js?

I have read somewhere that 2d elements can be applied to 3d faces, I do not know if this is limited to images or other 'flat' elements.

I would need to create interface elements in the canvas, a form, buttons, stats, etc.
It is for a tweet visualisation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to use a canvas as the texture in a three.js mesh. For example, see:

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Texture-From-Canvas.html

For an example where the texture is updated repeatedly, see:

http://stemkoski.github.com/Three.js/Texture-Animation.html